React routing, the generated URL does not match the path
I dont understand why the routing is not working
Problem:
I am encountering a 404 error despite the constructed URL matching the path.
Code Explanation:
Below is the function used to construct the URL:
const handleCardClick = (title, address) => {
    try {
        const formattedTitle = title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        const streetMatch = address.match(/^\s*(\[\w\s\]+?)\s*,/);
        const street = streetMatch ? streetMatch[1].toLowerCase() : '';
        const cityMatch = address.match(/\b(\w+)\s*$/);
        const city = cityMatch ? cityMatch[1].toLowerCase() : '';
        const formattedStreet = street.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        const formattedCity = city.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        const route = `/shop/${formattedTitle}-${formattedStreet}-${formattedCity}`;
        console.log("Constructed Route:", route);
        navigate(route);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred during navigation:", error);
    }
};

The App.tsx component sets up the routing:
import Home from "./routes/Home/Home.tsx";
import React from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import Login from "./routes/Login/Login.tsx";
import SignUp from "./routes/SignUp/SignUp.tsx";
import SignUpLogin from "./routes/SignUpLogin/SignUpLogin.tsx";
import Search from "./routes/Search/Search.tsx";
import Shop from "./routes/Shop/Shop.tsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
    { path: 'signup', element: <SignUp /> },
    { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
    { path: 'signup-login', element: <SignUpLogin /> },
    { path: 'search', element: <Search /> },
    { path: '/shop/:title-:street-:city', element: <Shop /> }
]);

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    );
};

export default App;

The Shop.tsx component retrieves parameters from the URL:
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Shop() { 
    const { title, street, city } = useParams();
    console.log('Title:', title);
    console.log('Street:', street);
    console.log('City:', city);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>Location: {street}, {city}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;

for the routes that the path is static, it works fine

Instead of { path: '/shop/:title-:street-:city', element: <Shop /> }
Try     { path: '/shop/:title/:street/:city', element: <Shop /> }

I have already tried this but i get the same error.

No, you will not get an error from setting the route to contain the discrete path parts, and you won't have to mess around with regexp to do what the router is intended to do. See @Drew's answer.

React-Router 6 cannot do partial path parameter matches.
You can:

Use discrete path segments
Defined route as:
{
  path: '/shop/:title/:street/:city',
  element: <Shop />
}

Form the navigation target:
const route = `/shop/${formattedTitle}/${formattedStreet}/${formattedCity}`;
navigate(route);

Access the discrete path segments:
const { title, street, city } = useParams();


Use a single parameter and some basic string manipulation
Defined route as:
{
  path: '/shop/:shop',
  element: <Shop />
}

Form the navigation target:
const route = `/shop/${formattedTitle}-${formattedStreet}-${formattedCity}`;
navigate(route);

Access the discrete values:
const { shop } = useParams();
const [title, street, city] = shop.split("-");




I found out the solution. In the handleCardClick function, I declared the route like this:
const handleCardClick = (title: string, address: string) => {
    try {
        const formattedTitle = title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        const streetMatch = address.match(/^\s*([\w\s]+?)\s*,/);
        const street = streetMatch ? streetMatch[1].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-') : '';
        const cityMatch = address.match(/\b(\w+)\s*$/);
        const city = cityMatch ? cityMatch[1].toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-') : '';

        const shopId = `${formattedTitle}-${street}-${city}`;
        const route = `/shop/${shopId}`;
        navigate(route);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred during navigation:", error);
    }
};

And the path in the App.tsx should be like this:
path: '/shop/:shopId'

